# How to use Gensim Doc2vec infer_vector() for large DataFrame?

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

I have created document vectors for a large corpus using Gensim's doc2vec.

`sentences=gensim.models.doc2vec.TaggedLineDocument('file.csv')`

`model = gensim.models.doc2vec.Doc2Vec(sentences,size = 10, window = 800, min_count = 1, workers=40, iter=10, dm=0)`

Now I am using Gensim's infer_vector() using those document vectors to create document vectors for another sample corpus

`Eg: model.infer_vector('This is a string')`

Is there a way to pass the entire DataFrame through infer_vector and get the output vectors for each line in the DataFrame?

Comment: `df['col'].apply(model.infer_vector)`?

Comment: Or, maybe this would work with a list: `model.infer_vector(df['col'])`

Comment: Thanks, df['col'].apply(model.infer_vector) worked

Answer (score 2):

`Doc2Vec` `infer_vector()` only takes individual text examples, as lists-of-word-tokens. So you can't pass in a batch of examples. (And, you shouldn't be passing in non-tokenized strings – but lists-of-tokens, preprocessed in the same manner as your training data was preprocessed.)

But, you might be able to use a function that multiply-applies `infer_vector()` for you, as the @COLDSPEED comment suggests. Still, the column should have lists-of-tokens, rather than strings-of-characters, if you want meaningful results.

Also, most users find `infer_vector()` works much better using non-default values for its `steps` parameter (much larger than its default of 5), and perhaps smaller values for its starting `alpha` parameter (such as more like the training default of 0.025 than the inference default of 0.1).

Answer (score 0):

@gojomo: Thanks for the answer, but I tried inferring using both tokenized rows as well as raw strings, and got the same document vector.

Is there a way to know if the document vector which are getting created are meaningful or not?